# React Native Push Notification without body

Tags: mobilepush, android, react-native

I've successfully installed the RN library for MC push notifications on my app (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk)

I'm able to register contacts and receive push notifications on Android and iOS.
The problem i'm experiencing with Android is that the push notifications on the device only shows the icon and title. It's not showing the notification body or an image if I send a push with media. (iOS working with no problems)

If i send the push via Firebase console I receive it with title, icon, body and image.
Any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the plugin on what version(s) of Android?

Comment: Hi Bill, we are using the 7.2.0 version of the plugin on Android 10.

Comment: This is what we have in build gradle:

buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.6.2"
        kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"